# Campo de busca com php e mysql. Como não diferenciar caracteres especiais?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um problema com um campo de busca em um site em php com banco MySql.

Tenho um registro no banco como "SIFÃO" e quando faço a busca como sifão, sifao ou SIFAO não retorna esse registro. Eu gostaria que não fizesse diferenciação de maiúsculas/minúsculas e caracteres especiais.

A tabela e os registros já estão convertidos para latin1 e estou usando essa colação na query, como podem ver no código abaixo. Nem assim está dando certo.

Segue o código:

```
  $texto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['texto']);
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT
  produtos.id as id,    
  produtos.nome as nome,
  produtos.descricao as descricao,
  produtos.tags as tags,
  produtos.url as url,
  ambientes.url as AmbienteUrl,
  categorias.url as CategoriaUrl,
  imagens.arquivo as ImagemArquivo
  FROM produtos
      INNER JOIN prod_amb ON prod_amb.produto_id = produtos.id
      INNER JOIN ambientes ON ambientes.id = prod_amb.ambiente_id
      INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = produtos.categoria_id
      INNER JOIN imagens ON imagens.produto_id = produtos.id
  WHERE (produtos.nome LIKE '%".$texto."%' collate latin1_swedish_ci
  OR produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$texto."%' collate latin1_swedish_ci
  OR produtos.tags LIKE '%".$texto."%' collate latin1_swedish_ci)
  AND produtos.situacao = 1 
  AND imagens.principal = 1
  GROUP BY produtos.id");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row['nome'];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, uma solução seria na query você converter tudo pra maiúsculo, ou pra minusculo, por exemplo:

`SELECT * FROM produto WHERE nome = UPPER('nomeProduto')`

a função UPPER() transforma o argumento passado pra maiúsculo, a função LOWER() transforma em manúsculo. No seu caso acho que daria pra fazer assim:

`...WHERE (produtos.nome LIKE UPPER('%".$texto."%')...`

Quanto aos acentos (ã, à, á) eu só vejo uma forma que seria fazendo uma função que removesse esses acentos dos caracteres, quando eu mechia com PHP não conhecia nada que fizesse isso automático, hoje pode ser que já exista.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Victor Hartur de Carvalho

uma função simples para remover os caracteres especiais:

```
function cleanStr($str)
{
    return preg_replace("/[^a-zA -Z0-9_.]/", "", strtr($str, "ÁÍÓÚÉÄÏÖÜËÀÌÒÙÈÃÕÂÎÔÛÊáíóúéäïöüëàìòùèãõâîôûêÇç", 
                                                             "AIOUEAIOUEAIOUEAOAIOUEaioueaioueaioueaoaioueCc"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

É preciso converter em minúsculas (ou maiúsculas), os dados do banco e as variáveis, antes de fazer a comparação:

```
WHERE (LOWER(produtos.nome) LIKE LOWER('%".$texto."%') collate latin1_swedish_ci
OR LOWER(produtos.descricao) LIKE LOWER('%".$texto."%') collate latin1_swedish_ci
OR LOWER(produtos.tags) LIKE LOWER('%".$texto."%') collate latin1_swedish_ci)
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.